# Transitions in a magnetic refrigeration

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

The graph below (see attached) shows the measured magnetization against temperature at room pressure for the material Gd and for another material for use in a magnetic refrigerator at room temperature.

1)Calculate the expected change of temperature of a thermally isolated piece of Gd when the field in which it is located slowly reduced from an induction of $H_1$ = 1.2T to $H_2$ = 0.8T starting at a temperature 300K. You may assume that the $M$ versus $T$ curve does not change appreciably with $H$ for $H$ in the range 0.8-1.2T. Additionally, assume that the molar specific heat capacity of Gd is $C_p = 3R J/K/mol$ of atoms, independent of temperature and field.  The formula mass of Gd is 157.25g/mol.

In a previous question, I showed that $$dT = - \frac{T}{C_{P}} \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{M}}{\partial T}\right)_{H,P} dH,$$
where $\mathcal{M}$ is the magnetic moment.  So, given $C_p$ I need to find the final temperature of the material and also the quantity $\partial \mathcal{M}/\partial T$.  The assumptions in the questions indicate that the gradient of the M versus T curve is approximately constant, but I am not sure how to find this value.  We are also to assume that $\mathcal{M} = MV$  The graph shows $M/\rho$ vs $T$ which is equivalent to $\mathcal{M}/m$ vs $T$.

Many thanks[image]